# No such file found while executing python file in gitbash

Tags: python, git-bash

[image: No such file found error]

I have been trying to execute a python file from gitbash. It seems my gitbash is not able to locate my file.

I thought python is not installed properly or maybe the environment variables are not set. However, I have set everything and when I execute `$ python --version` in gitbash, it comes up with Python 3.6.4, which I guess means python and path variables are set properly.

Now, when I write `$python filename.py` then it comes up with an error: `No such file and directly found`, but I do have a file with the name `challenge1.py` installed in the same folder.

Comment: If you went to all the trouble of making a screenshot, it would have helped to include a directory listing so we could see if the file was there or not.

Comment: Always worse a try: use an absolute path!

Answer (score 0):

In your bash, you are in `~`, which by default is `%USERPROFILE%` (`C:\USers\yourLogin`)

So unless you have created `challenge1.py` in that folder, you need to cd first to the actual folder including that file

```
cd /c/path/to/file
```